# Join query using Codeigniter with where condition to return all rows and number of rows

Tags: mysql

we have 2 tables `user_details` and `shipments`
we have to get all the `order_id` of each user from `shipments` table where `shipment_count` in `user_details` table is less than or equal to `4` and `onb_status` !='1' in `shipments` table

[image: user_details (table)]

[image: shipments (table)]

[image: output]

Comment: post in not related to php and highlighted the main keywords like table name fieldname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this one.
The mysql query:

> select u.user_email as email, s.from_address as from, s.to_address as
>   to, s.order_id, u.user_id from shipments s left join user_details u on
>   u.user_id = s.user_id where  u.shipment_count <= 4 and s.onb_status 
>   !=1;

```
$this->db->select('u.user_email as email, s.from_address as from, s.to_address as to, s.order_id, u.user_id');
$this->db->from('shipments as s');
$this->db->where('u.shipment_count <=', 4);
$this->db->where('s.onb_status !=', 1);
$this->db->join('user_details as u', ' u.user_id = s.user_id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

model

```
function get_data(){
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from("shipments AS t1");
$this->db->join("user_details AS t2", "t1.user_id = t2.user_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
    if ($query->num_rows() >0){ 
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $results = $data;
        }
    return $results;
    }
```

controller

```
function data()
{
    $data['results'] = $this->your model->get_data();
    $this->load->view('your view');
}
```

view

```
  <table border="2">
       <thead>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>from</th>
            <th>to</th>
            <th>order_id</th>
            <th>order_id</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($result as $data) :
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $data->from_address; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->to_addres; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->order_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->user_id?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i hope it works